# Unable to load parquet delta data after re-uploading it to same place

Tags: databricks, delta-lake

I have a testcase which generates parquet & delta data into storage. I can then use Azure databricks to load this into a dataframe and query it.

However, if I download this parquet & delta data, then remove that data from storage, and re-upload the same data back into its original location, I can no longer run the same query on the same data, with error '...is not a Delta table' being the response. Is there a way to achieve this?

In total, I'm trying to enable a way to setup a system in order to run a test, where the test relies on this parquet & delta data already being present. I was hoping to be able to just upload this data directly, before running the test (rather than running a system to generate this initial data), however, as noted here, a straight upload of archived data, doesn't initially work.

Comment: have you checked that you also upload the `_delta_log` subfolder?

Comment: @AlexOtt that is correct, the delta log folder was reuploaded too